# What does glassy essence mean?

Tags: phrase-usage

"... but man, proud man,
Drest in a little brief authority,
Most ignorant of what he's most assured,
His glassy essence, like an angry ape,
Plays such fantastic tricks before high heaven
As make the angels weep; who, with our spleens,
Would all themselves laugh mortal."  Here is a quote from Shakespeare's Measure for Measure.  What does "glassy essence" mean here?

Comment: What does your research with dictionaries tell you? Have you found definitions of *glassy* and *essence*? Is there a combination of those definitions which would make sense in this context?

Comment: And which makes sense when compared to an "angry ape"?   :)

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of notes and analysis on pretty much any passage of Shakespeare you could think of online. A quick Google search came up with this:

> His "glassy essence" — the fragility of his soul

Source: http://www.enotes.com/shakespeare-quotes/brief-authority